# django - template key error after uploading data in database

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I just imported 57,000 records into a MySql database and when I go in admin and click on the model corresponding to the records I get this mess below. Any ideas?

KeyError at /admin/donate/donor/

10

Error during template rendering
In template /Users/user/Development/project/project/templates/admin/donate/donor/change_list.html, error at line 98

```
 {% block result_list %}
97            {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
98            {% result_list cl %} ##THIS IS THROWING THE ERROR
99            {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
100       {% endblock %}
```

On the traceback at the bottom I get this:

{True: 'yes', False: 'no', None: 'unknown'}[field_val])

Local Vars: field_val 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that a boolean field got data entered in it that wasent 1 or 0.

I changed them all to 0 and bam, worked. The Local Vars: field_val 10 was telling me that the invalid number '10' was throwing the error